# Linking SwiftViewController to xib containing a UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, interface-builder

Hello every one and thank you in advance, I am new to Interface builder and Swift so it could be one or a combination of the technologies fooling up on.

What I am trying to make is a simple UIView that contains a UITableView in interface builder, and link it to a viewController that I have created in swift. The error I am getting is as fallows:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I believe the issue is because i am calling numberOfRowsInSection on UIViewController and not my class SearchesMainViewController.

SearchesMainViewController.swift looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SearchesMainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var contentTableView: UITableView?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = contentTableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
}
```

And here are the values and connections I have made on my xib for File's Owner

[image: File Owners Identity tab]
[image: File Owners Connections tab]

Thanks again for your time and help I really appreciate it :)

**edit**
this is how i am initializing the SearchesMainView in AppDelegate.swift
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this code in viewDidLoad, fix your problem :

```
contentTableView?.delegate = self
contentTableView?.dataSource = self
```

Comment: I gave this a try and it did not work, same error occurs. It looks like the outlets and connections are trying to be made on UIViewController instead of SearchesMainViewController, I believe there is an error before this life cycle method is called

Comment: How do you do init your SearchesMainViewController?

Comment: In AppDelegate.swift I have:
let searchesMainView = UIViewController(nibName: "SearchesMainView", bundle: nil)

Comment: You may be on to something, 
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
    }
are both not being called

Comment: your init was wrong i think :  `let searchesMainView = SearchesMainViewController(nibName: "SearchesMainView", bundle: nil)`

Comment: You were correct I also needed to add the init methods:
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    internal override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }